# basic rails on directing to a new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm wanting to have a url path in rails that looks like this.

```
baseurl/event/gigs
```

Basically the gigs will have its own show file

So im not sure if this is my php kicking in, However, I've got the file structure up like this

```
event > gigs > index.html.erb
```

Is this the correct way? and if so will i then have a controller like this?

```
class GigsController < EventController

def index
@vars will go here unless their inside the eventcontroller already?
end

end
```

**Edit**

So i had a blonde moment,

Whats happening now, Is i'm trying to get the gigs page to work but im getting stuck on the show method trying to get gigs and an id.

The url i'm putting in is `/event/gigs`

The error im getting

Couldn't find Event with 'id'= gigs

Ideas?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to say but looks like you don't understand how controllers works. Check out this chapter in ror guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: Ah kinda understand, I've got to make a change to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a resources :events, which by default generates many routes:

One of them is the `GET /events/:id` route. The URL you're visiting is hitting this route, and it's searching the DB for an Event ActiveRecord object with the :id 'gigs'.

I believe what you're wanting to do is define a static 'gigs' page under the `/events/` namespace,

To do so, add this to routes.rb:

```
  resources :events do
    collection do
      get '/gigs' => "events#gigs"
    end
  end
```

The file structure you're looking for, if you want to have a static `/events/gigs` page, is the following:

Your controller where you will supply variables and logic for the gigs action:

`app/controllers/events_controller.rb`

Where you will have the following:

```
def gigs
    # Logic goes here.
end
```

And the view in question:

`app/views/events/gig.html.erb`

P.S - Like said above in the comments, you should skim over [guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) in order to understand basic Rails concepts (folder structure, what controllers are and how routing works..).

Comment: SO i've done everything stated. And i have doen a rake on the routes etc. However, It still keep searching the db. I've got in the show a `@event = Events.find(params[:id])` which is what its getting stuck on still.

Comment: Have you restarted your rails server? Routes might not've been reloaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the output of `rake routes`. That will tell you how the URI's will map to controller actions. That's always a good way of debugging this kind of problem.

But from what you have posted and what @GigaBass recommended, I believe you should be pointing you browser at `/events/gigs`.

Cheers,

Niels